# Opencart pagination URL issue. Multiple URL giving same output

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, opencart

I have enabled SEO links in Opencart. Also written HTACCESS file. But still, the below two links are giving the same page as the output. I have enabled infinite scrolling on the page.

http://www.yoursite.com/green-dresses?page=2 and 
http://www.yoursite.com/green-dresses

Can any one suggest me how to remove ?page=2 from URL

Answer (score 0):

Use the following rule in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^green-dresses$ /green-dresses?page=2 [L]
```

This will remove `?page=2` from the end of your URLs and leave you with: `http://www.yoursite.com/green-dresses`.

Comment: But this only solves it temporarily. If I have n number of such links then I have to write for all of them. That is not good

Comment: Then maybe you should have specified that in your question. Instead of mentioning it in a comment after I had answered. Your question is very specific to the one page.